# Is it a security issue to pin the version of the "certifi" package in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, certificate, pip

I have a web service that uses the *requests* library to make https requests to a different, external service.

As part of my deployment process, whenever there's a change to the list of dependencies, I use `pip freeze` to regenerate the `requirements.txt` file, which is stored in my code repository and processed by my PaaS provider to set up the application environment.

Today, I noticed this line in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
certifi==14.05.14
```

That is, the [certifi](https://certifi.io) package is pinned down to a version that is no longer the latest.

1. Is this a security issue (does it mean that my trusted root certificates are not up-to-date)?
2. If so - what would be the best way to change my deployment process (which is, I think, fairly standard) to solve this issue?